# Java EE CDI Class-based injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I am reading up on Java EE CDI and I am a confused about how class-based Resource injection works

The Java EE 6 tutorial gives the following example usage:

```
@Resource(name="myMessageQueue",
                type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory")
public class SomeMessageBean {
...
}
```

I get how it is declared but how is the declared resource supposed to be used in the `SomeMessageBeanClass`? What is the `myMessageQueue` resource injected into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Resource` in an annotation that originates from EJB.

Its lineage goes back to the days before injection into fields was possible. In those days, "injection" meant putting something into a kind of map that is associated with each EJB bean; the so-called ENC (Enterprise Naming Context).

You can access this "map" by requesting the "java:/comp" namespace from the `InitialContext` when inside an EJB, or directly from the EJB context (which you have to inject as well).

These days using the ENC seems rare. Field injection is much more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Follow up question, if one has to obtain the resource from JNDI InitialContext anyways then what is the point in declaring the class-based Resource annotation?

Comment: There's relatively little point to it that way. It originates from the XML variant. With that you can declare in an (external) XML file what gets put in the ENC of a given bean. The `@Resource` just mirrors the XML.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I read up on ENC and now I understand (I think) how the API is supposed to work, though I do think that the API this way is more complex than it needs to be.